# Screen Flickering & Freezing problem

Tags: 18.04, dell, freeze, inspiron, flicker

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in Dell Inspiron 3542 laptop for 2 years. Now my laptop screen is always flickering & get stuck / freeze in every 3 seconds. On the time of screen stuck, mouse, keyboard etc are working but it is not able to see changes in the screen. Please suggest a method to fix my problem...

Comment: How could you use 18.04 for two years?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a hardware issue to me. If you boot to a cd or usb drive does the screen still show this behavior?  I'd suggest reaching out to dell for support/repair.